# Can't set a BOOL to yes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, boolean

I've ran into this problem and so far I can't find any answers. so a have a BOOL property and I am trying to set it to YES/TRUE/true ( I have tried them all) but whenever I check the BOOL it always returns NO/FALSE/false. Below is my code

```
[myObject setAllowReg:YES];
myObject.allowReg = YES;
if (myObject.allowReg)
{
    NSLog(@"YES");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

The output to this is always "NO". This must be something really simple that I am missing but it seems whatever I try doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the part of the code where the allowReg variable is declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beat guess is that `myObject.allowReg` is `nil` and probably `myObject` is `nil`.

Add some NSLog statements to help figure this out:

```
NSLog(@"myObject: %@", myObject);
NSLog(@"myObject.allowReg: %i", myObject.allowReg);
```

Advice: In debugging break everything down to the simplest statements and test each step along the way.

Comment: Lol yeah you are right, I was executing the code before creating myObject. It must be one of those days :(

Answer (score 2):

`myObject` is probably `nil`. You can send messages to `nil` objects, they always return a 0 value.